# How to save multiple data in 1 column SQL

Tags: mysql, multiple-value

I know, there already is similar questions, but I can't find a good answer at my problem.

I'm developing a social network, I have all my users in a table, but each users must be able to save multiple post from the website.

**My Question is:**

How can I store all the saved post for each user without creating a new table for each users. I know this is bad to do this, so I'm looking for an alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just need a middle table (for example names `user_post`) that have 2 columns : `user_id` and `post_id`

this is a simple implementation of a `many-to-many relationship`

Comment: You're right, I didn't though to do only one middle table with all users and posts just for the saved posts, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You only need a table to store all posts call it `posts` table with structure like this:

```
|post_id|user_id|title|content|etc..|
```

So you can do something to save posts and identify them by `user_id`.
It's called `one-to-many` relationship, you can search more about `database relationships`.

Comment: I already have a table like this one, but how can I say that a particular user, has saved 5 posts from my posts table on his profile for example, and retrieve these only 5 posts

Comment: That is `many-to-many` relationship, you can create `saved_posts` table with structure like this `user_id|post_id`.
So if user save 5 posts just insert 5 records there